# Algorithm for getting the overlapping of a sequence of string in an array on another array

Tags: .net, arrays, string, algorithm

I wan to build an algorithm which able to give the overlapping indices of the elements found in the two arrays.

e.g. I have two arrays of string

Array1: {"a","c","h",**"d","a","o","m"**}

Array2: {**"d","a","o","m"**,"c","e","o","m","c","z","e","l","p","v","c","z","c"}

It should return me the indices of the array1 and array2 in this way

*x1,y1={3,6}*
*x2,y2={0,3}*

It means the sequence of the string in the array should match and as long as the string values match we need to do that and make sure that every record will be unique by their previous record matching.

Waiting for the answers and responses , if questions then please let me know.

Like an example, I have a table in database where i inserting the records, and every record which i want to insert should be very unique. So at a time of insertion, we do have an array of records which needed to insert in a batch. So if i say, I do have the record in the database table is in the form:

**colum1**
hash1
hash2
hash3
hash4
hash5

And I want to insert a bunch of records in the database which are in the form:
hash3 
hash4 
hash5
hash6
hash7
hash8

Then the resultant of the table should be loook like this
**colum1**
hash1
hash2
hash3
hash4
hash5
*hash6
hash7
hash8*

But, if the array which need to be inserted in the database will be in the format like 
hash2
hash3
hash4
hash6

then it should be treated as a whole new entry and will be inserted in the database as a whole.

Hope I am clear this time to elaborate my problem

Comment: While you are waiting, take some time to post the code that you have already written and explain the problems you have.  Without showing us your code your question appears to be of the 'pleez write my code for me' variety -- typically such questions get poor answers here on SO.

Comment: Here's a nudge find substrings of the smaller string among the two and for each substring element use biggerString.Contains to see if it contains the element you seek whichever returns a true value find the index using IndexOf() not sure what is the time and space complexity you're looking for.

Comment: What about "c" matching.  How about the first "a" matching.  Clean up the question and show some code.  I would parse the two strings into char arrays and have two loops but SO is not for code generation.

Comment: Code is a quite away for me now, as I am playing a little bit with the algo right now. Although I am not looking for the code but looking for a good algorithm just psedeo code which make me easy to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're referring to is called the Longest Common Substring problem (not to be confused with another problem about strings and an LCS acronym - longest common subsequence). As usual, the best explanation is in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem :)

In short - if the strings are really short and you're a very lazy programmer, the fastest way of doing that is to check all substrings of arr2 against arr1. This will take about n^2*m time (if arr2 if of length n, and arr1 is of length m) - which is a lot of time for long strings.

If your strings are longer / you are less lazy, the best algorithm using suffix trees will give you linear running time.

Comment: I think you mean n^2 * m^2? Also is better to quote main part of wiki article, to make your answer more interesting.

Comment: Its time which considers a lot in my algorithm and even a little milliseconds will cost me a lot..believe me..it definitely cost a lot.

Comment: @Saeed - depending on the implementation, but anyway too much. Thanks for the advice about the wiki link.

Comment: @Manish - that's the best you can do if you want an exact answer. It's also asymptotically optimal (linear is as much time as you would spend just reading the strings). Is there any preprocessing you can do?

Comment: yeah actually I can do some optimization in the flow, like there could be 5 cases we can divide the scenario of occurring the PART OF ARRAY1 in PART OF ARRAY2. AND the cases are as follows... **1.** a left part of the array2 consists in the right part of the array1.  **2.** a left part of the array1 consists in the right part of array2. **3.** whole array2 consists in the array1. **4**. whole array1 consists in the array2. **5.** no part of array1 matches in array2.

Comment: Sorry - but I don't think that this gives any improvement. Just looking for the shorter array in the longer array will take N+M time (just reading them, and then applying some simple scheme like Rabin-Karp). Unless you are ok with sampling/looking for limited length matches - your fastest bet is the suffix tree.

Comment: yeah, sampling is what actually i am looking for. I made an update to the question also , can you have a look   ,may be there you can find the exact scenario which i want to work on.